# Cron php5 too many processes

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron:

```
* * * * php5 /home/update_tunein.php
* * * * sleep 15; php5 /home/update_tunein.php
* * * * sleep 30; php5 /home/update_tunein.php
* * * * sleep 45; php5 /home/update_tunein.php
```

Every time cron makes a new proccess. These proccesses makes CPU usage 100%. How to make cron do only 1 proccess? Or maybe how to kill proccess after work?

```
... && killall php5
```

isn't working. Help me please

Comment: Maybe you should exit() in your php code at some point. 100% cpu usage and never exiting means infinite loop.

Comment: I have tried. It isn't helpful.

Comment: Is your php code supposed to terminate at some point ? also, can you show the output for `which php5` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have many entries and time of that entries overlapping .
you can do this way

```
   * * * * * ~/script.sh
```

put  in script.sh file like below that will create 3 background process. for more info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800/how-to-run-scripts-every-5-seconds-using-cron)

```
(sleep 15 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 30 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 45 && /path/to/task) &
```

EDIT : it is bad approach to use crontab for less then 1 min  and also it not support less than 1 min directly . better then this you have to create you own script to run it . if your task take more than 15 sec than some wrong may happen.

Comment: Appears 2-5 processes, One is needed

Comment: you can take help from this post :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/cron-running-job-every-15-seconds